# Why is the order of #include statements so important?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

In my program (wxWidgets, code::blocks), I noticed some behaviour I don't quite understand. If I write my header like this:

```
#ifndef RECORDTHREAD_H
#define RECORDTHREAD_H

#include <wx/thread.h>
#include <wx/dialog.h>
#include <wx/string.h>

#include "Serial.h"

class RecordTrackDialog;

class RecordThread : public wxThread
{
    public:
        RecordThread(RecordTrackDialog* parent);
        virtual ~RecordThread();
    protected:
    private:
        virtual ExitCode Entry();

        Serial m_serial;
};

#endif // RECORDTHREAD_H
```

(with `#include "Serial.h"` as last include statement) all works fine, though when I change the include statements like this:

```
#ifndef RECORDTHREAD_H
#define RECORDTHREAD_H

#include "Serial.h"

#include <wx/thread.h>
#include <wx/dialog.h>
#include <wx/string.h>
```

I get errors like this:

```
||=== Build: Debug in WindowsDgpsGUI (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\wxWidgets-3.0.2\include\wx\msw\winundef.h||In function 'HWND__* CreateDialog(HINSTANCE, LPCTSTR, HWND, DLGPROC)':|
C:\wxWidgets-3.0.2\include\wx\msw\winundef.h|38|error: cannot convert 'LPCTSTR {aka const char*}' to 'LPCWSTR {aka const wchar_t*}' for argument '2' to 'HWND__* CreateDialogParamW(HINSTANCE, LPCWSTR, HWND, DLGPROC, LPARAM)'|
C:\wxWidgets-3.0.2\include\wx\msw\winundef.h||In function 'HFONT__* CreateFont(int, int, int, int, int, DWORD, DWORD, DWORD, DWORD, DWORD, DWORD, DWORD, DWORD, LPCTSTR)':|
C:\wxWidgets-3.0.2\include\wx\msw\winundef.h|69|error: cannot convert 'LPCTSTR {aka const char*}' to 'LPCWSTR {aka const wchar_t*}' for argument '14' to 'HFONT__* CreateFontW(int, int, int, int, int, DWORD, DWORD, DWORD, DWORD, DWORD, DWORD, DWORD, DWORD, LPCWSTR)'|
C:\wxWidgets-3.0.2\include\wx\msw\winundef.h||In function 'HWND__* CreateWindow(LPCTSTR, LPCTSTR, DWORD, int, int, int, int, HWND, HMENU, HINSTANCE, LPVOID)':|
C:\wxWidgets-3.0.2\include\wx\msw\winundef.h|94|error: cannot convert 'LPCTSTR {aka const char*}' to 'LPCWSTR {aka const wchar_t*}' for argument '2' to 'HWND__* CreateWindowExW(DWORD, LPCWSTR, LPCWSTR, DWORD, int, int, int, int, HWND, HMENU, HINSTANCE, LPVOID)'|
C:\wxWidgets-3.0.2\include\wx\msw\winundef.h||In function 'HMENU__* LoadMenu(HINSTANCE, LPCTSTR)':|
C:\wxWidgets-3.0.2\include\wx\msw\winundef.h|111|error: cannot convert 'LPCTSTR {aka const char*}' to 'LPCWSTR {aka const wchar_t*}' for argument '2' to 'HMENU__* LoadMenuW(HINSTANCE, LPCWSTR)'|
C:\wxWidgets-3.0.2\include\wx\msw\winundef.h||In function 'HWND__* FindText(LPFINDREPLACE)':|
C:\wxWidgets-3.0.2\include\wx\msw\winundef.h|126|error: cannot convert 'LPFINDREPLACE {aka FINDREPLACEA*}' to 'LPFINDREPLACEW {aka FINDREPLACEW*}' for argument '1' to 'HWND__* FindTextW(LPFINDREPLACEW)'|
C:\wxWidgets-3.0.2\include\wx\msw\winundef.h||In function 'HICON__* LoadIcon(HINSTANCE, LPCTSTR)':|
C:\wxWidgets-3.0.2\include\wx\msw\winundef.h|311|error: cannot convert 'LPCTSTR {aka const char*}' to 'LPCWSTR {aka const wchar_t*}' for argument '2' to 'HICON__* LoadIconW(HINSTANCE, LPCWSTR)'|
C:\wxWidgets-3.0.2\include\wx\msw\winundef.h||In function 'HBITMAP__* LoadBitmap(HINSTANCE, LPCTSTR)':|
C:\wxWidgets-3.0.2\include\wx\msw\winundef.h|324|error: cannot convert 'LPCTSTR {aka const char*}' to 'LPCWSTR {aka const wchar_t*}' for argument '2' to 'HBITMAP__* LoadBitmapW(HINSTANCE, LPCWSTR)'|
||=== Build failed: 7 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|
```

I don't quite understand this behaviour, because the header is a thread and the error comes from the dialog that uses this thread. Can anyone explain why C++ (or wxWidgets) behaves like this?

Edit:

The includes of Serial.h

```
#ifndef SERIAL_H
#define SERIAL_H

#include <windows.h>
//#include <wx/msw/winundef.h>
#include <stdio.h> // necessary for sprintf
#include <string>
```

It seems to fit Marco's comment, but I cannot include the  part...

Comment: What is `Serial.h`? As you're using double-quotes it should mean that it's a file in your project - and if your own header depends on other headers then you've written `Serial.h` incorrectly. `Serial.h` should be responsible for its own includes.

Comment: Possibly related: https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/WxMSW_Issues#The_windows.h_Header_File.2C_Macros_and_Compiling_Errors

Comment: Show us Serial.h.

Comment: It means one or more headers are broken. The order should not matter in correctly written code.

Comment: @Martin edited question

Comment: It means that something in `Serial.h` depends on declarations or definitions in one or more of the `wx` headers.   Either `Serial.h` needs to include those headers it depends on, or you always need to ensure other files that `#include "Serial.h"` only do so after including the `wx` headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `<windows.h>` defines different symbols depending on whether `UNICODE` standard (under Windows, that is) macro is defined or not. If you include wxWidgets headers first, which assume Unicode build by default, they define `UNICODE` for you before including `<windows.h>` and everything is good.

If you include `<windows.h>` first, then `UNICODE` is not defined at this time, but when you include wxWidgets headers later they use `wxUSE_UNICODE=1` (which is, again, the default value) resulting in the compilation problems you're observing.

The simplest way to ensure you never have such problems is to define `UNICODE` globally, in the project settings or makefile.

Answer (score 1):

As comments have pointed out it's probably because `Serial.h` relies on definitions in the 3 `wx\xxxx` files you include the main file (`RecordThread.h`?).

Add them to `Serial.h` like this and you will have the equivalent of what you had before.

```
#ifndef SERIAL_H
#define SERIAL_H

#include <wx/thread.h>
#include <wx/dialog.h>
#include <wx/string.h>

#include <windows.h>
//#include <wx/msw/winundef.h>
#include <stdio.h> // necessary for sprintf
#include <string>
```

If you're going to do it properly you should work out which one (or ones) you actually need in `Serial.h` but adding all of them should clear the error.

When compiling the preprocessor handles `#include` by acting as if the specified file was copied into the main file at the location of the `#include`. That is a recursive process and files can `#include` files that `#include` files and so on.

There seems to be a lot of mysticism about `#include` and the preprocessor in general amongst novices. It's really just a text manipulation tool.

In many places in modern C you must declare (introduce/define) a symbol/identifier before using it. If that symbol/identifier is declared in a header file you should `#include` that file before using it.

Answer (score 0):

Just some common practices to follow up , this may not answer your question , but point you to right direction:

- Always make you you don't `#include` same header file in same file , it means confusing but understand it using following diagram:

**Valid:**

```
-#include "some.h"
-#include "some1.h"
```

**Valid:**

```
-#include "some.h"
--#include "some1.h"
```

**Not Valid:**

```
-#include "some.h"
-#include "some1.h"
--#include "some.h"
```

So not nesting unless you know what you are doing..

One possible solution to your problem would to include `wx\thread.h`, `wx\dialog.h`, `wx\string.h` within `Serial.h` , try it , and let me know

Why calling `#include` in order matters ?

Because it only make sense if you understand something like this , Ali needs to clean repair his car , Ali don't know how to repair his car , so Ali will call mechanic to repair it , so Here we can say that **(Ali depends on Mechanic)**:

```
- #include "mechanic.h"

- #include "Ali.h"
```

Comment: I understand what you mean, but from what each of these classes does it does not make much sense to include these headers in `Serial.h` as Serial just opens and reads from serial communication and is a class someone else wrote and the Record part is the one that really needs these...Record opens serial communication, parses the input and processes it further.

Comment: There are several cases when , nothing make sense but you have to do it anyway , because that is the only workaround, try to call them in order they are dependent to each other in a single file , may it be main or any of the header file , why calling in order matters , let's discuss in answer

Comment: This is just wrong. If some1.h needs names from some.h, then some1.h should #include some.h. If a source file needs names from some.h and some1.h, then it should #include both files. The code marked "Not Valid:" is perfectly fine, provided only that some.h has proper include guards.

Comment: @PeteBecker its best not to confuse beginner with `guards` stuff , good practice is to try not to use them , am i wrong ?

Comment: You are absolutely wrong. Include guards are a fundamental tool of C and C++ programming. Not using them leads to mysterious interdependencies, order dependencies, and confusing error messages.